# Polymorphic functions in Record Types Haskell

Tags: haskell

i've stumbled upon a behaviour I can't explain in Haskell. I'm trying to store a polymorphic function in a Record Type, which I want to use in a ReaderT Monad. When I get my function with `asks`, the compiler doesn't recognize it as polymorphic and seems to fix the type on the first occurance of the function. I created a minimal example of this in ghci:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types             #-}

data Test = Test {f :: (forall a. a -> a)}

runReaderT (asks f 
            >>= \f -> (liftIO . putStrLn $ show (f 2 :: Int)) 
                   >> (liftIO . putStrLn $ show (f "hello"))
           ) (Test id)
```

When trying to run this, I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘"hello"’
In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘(f "hello")’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘show (f "hello")’
```

However, following code works:

```
runReaderT (ask 
            >>= \(Test f) -> (liftIO . putStrLn $ show (f 2 :: Int))     
                          >> (liftIO . putStrLn $ show (f "hello"))
           ) (Test id)
```

So is it something special with `asks`? I'm grateful for any advice on this.

Comment: I guess it has to do with `f` appearing after the \ if I'm not mistaken, lambda arguments are still monomorphic unless you state otherwise.

Comment: Just a heads up: Rank2Types is an obsolete extension, aliased to RankNTypes. (And RankNTypes just allows you to write `forall`s. No higher-rank type inference in GHC, as Ingo's answer details.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time I checked, GHC could not infer higher rank types. Thus, when you have

```
\f ->  ... f x .... f y
```

the `f` can never be polymorphic.

There are only two places where the type of some variable is so obvious that type inference recognizes the higher rank type: in patterns that declare higher rank fields and in the LHS  of annotated functions.

It also should work to give the type explicitly, like in

```
\(f :: forall a.a -> a) -> .... f x ... f y
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! This explains it. So matching on \(Test f) -> is the first case you mention, right?